# Conversions from Foo<Derived> to Foo<Base>

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand conversions from things like `Foo<Derived>` to `Foo<Base>`. As an example, if I have the following code snippet (long, sorry):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual void print() const = 0;
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "Derived::print const\n"; }
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "Derived::print\n"; }
};

template <typename R>
class BasePtr
{
public:
  BasePtr() : ptr_(std::make_shared<R>())
  {
  }

  void print() const
  {
    ptr_->print();
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<R> ptr_;
};

/* Takes const shared ptr */
void takesConstSharedPtr(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& base)
{
  base->print();
}

void takesConstSharedPtrConst(const std::shared_ptr<const Base>& base)
{
  base->print();
}

/* Takes non-const shared ptr */
void takesSharedPtr(std::shared_ptr<Base>& base)
{
  base->print();
}

void takesSharedPtrConst(std::shared_ptr<const Base>& base)
{
  base->print();
}

/* Takes base ptr class */
void takesBase(BasePtr<Base>& base)
{
  base.print();
}

void takesBaseConst(BasePtr<const Base>& base)
{
  base.print();
}

/* Takes const base ptr class */
void takesConstBase(const BasePtr<Base>& base)
{
  base.print();
}

void takesConstBaseConst(const BasePtr<const Base>& base)
{
  base.print();
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
  BasePtr<Derived> basePtr;

  // Works!
  takesConstSharedPtr(ptr);
  takesConstSharedPtrConst(ptr);

  // Does not works...
  takesSharedPtr(ptr);
  takesSharedPtrConst(ptr);

  takesConstBase(basePtr);
  takesConstBaseConst(basePtr);

  takesBase(basePtr);
  takesConstBase(basePtr);
}
```

I get the compile errors on the last 6 calls in the main function, but no compile errors on the first two calls. If I comment out the last 6 calls, I can compile successfully and get the expected output:

```
Derived::print
Derived::print const
```

What is going on here? Why is `shared_ptr<Derived>` able to be converted to `const shared_ptr<Base>` and `const shared_ptr<const Base>`, but not the non-const versions? Also, how can I write `BasePtr` to be able to mimic the behavior of `shared_ptr`?

The compile errors I get are the following:

```
'void takesBase(BasePtr<Base> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'BasePtr<Derived>' to 'BasePtr<Base> &'
```

And combinations thereof.

Comment: what is the reason you are calling  ptr_(std::make_shared<R>()) on derived constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might think that somehow a `BasePtr<Derived>` reference was somehow trivially convertible to a `BasePtr<Base>` reference, but this is not the case. Those two types refer to completely unrelated classes that have no inheritance relationship between them. Their template parameters may, but the relationship between two template parameters doesn't have anything to do with the relationship between the instantiated templates.

The people who designed `shared_ptr` knew this, and still wanted `shared_ptr`s to be usable like regular pointers, and to seemingly automatically convert if the thing they were pointing at had a parent/derived relationship.

So, instead of those conversions being automatic, they are actually handled by a special template conversion constructor defined as a member of `::std::shared_ptr`. These create a brand new `shared_ptr` that points at an object of the base type. This new object is a temporary, and therefor you can't pass it as a non-const reference parameter.

Here is how you might do this for your `BasePtr` class, though this is simplistic. Looking at the code for `shared_ptr` it looks for a lot of edge cases where a conversion would or wouldn't be allowed (pointers to arrays vs. pointers to individual objects is a big part of that) that I'm not accounting for here.

```
template <typename T>
class BasePtr {
  public:
   BasePtr() : ptr_(new T) { }

   // This conversion constructor will fail if other.ptr_ cannot be
   // assigned to ptr_ without any explicit conversion.
   template <typename U>
   BasePtr(const BasePtr<U> &other) : ptr_(other.ptr_) { }

   // You would also need a converting version of operator = that
   // was written in much the same way.
};
```

Also, if you think about it, what you want to have happen wouldn't work for regular pointers either.

```
class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

void foo(Base *&baz)
{
}

void bar(Base * const &qux)
{
}

void trivially_works(Derived *&d)
{
}

void testing()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived;
    foo(d); // Failed with a compiler error, for same reason as BasePtr<Base> &.
    bar(d); // Works for same reason as const BasePtr<Base> &
    trivially_works(d); // And this works because you're passing a reference to d, not a temporary.

    Base *b = d; // Works of course
    foo(b); // And now this works because it's a reference to b, not a temporary.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to know about templates is they are not a class in themselves and they do not have a relationship with each other unless explicitly stated in the definition

```
template<typename T> class Foo; // not a class, only a template to make a class from
typedef Foo<Bar> FooBar; // an entirely new class with no relationships
```

Knowing this even if we have a base class `BarA` and a subclass `BarB` Any class made from `Foo` is still a new class, so `Foo<BarA>` and `Foo<BarB>` are still entirely new classes and not related to each other, so no conversion between them will be good outside of reinterpret casts which is not advised.

Edit: A little more info on what your trying to do

What you would need to do to allow this conversion would be a template conversion function for examples sake heres an untested attempt

```
template<typename T> class Foo {

    Foo(T* const t_contained) {

        // set up stuff
    }

    template<typename T_CONVERT_TO>
    FOO<T_CONVERT_TO> asFoo() {

        // assuming m_contained can convert to Foo<T_CONVERT_TO>'s m_contained
        // if not it'll complain, so you know asFoo can only be given covnertable values
        return Foo<T_CONVERT_TO>( m_contained );
    }
};

Foo<BarB> fooBarB;
Foo<BarA> fooBarA = fooBarB.asFoo<BarB>();
```

Again, not tested, and I don't know that it would work with shared_ptr, but its the general idea behind converting between template types